# Decoupling many second-order linear ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, linear-algebra

I am doing mesh/loop analysis on a fairly complex electrical circuit, and the result is a system of 45 second-order coupled differential equations such as

$$ (\ddot{q}_{23} - \ddot{q}_{24}) L_{3} + (\dot{q}_{23} - \dot{q}_{24}) R_{5} + (q_{14} - q_{24}) S_{12} = \ddot{q}_{24} L_{4} + (\ddot{q}_{24} - \ddot{q}_{25}) L_{5} + (\dot{q}_{24} - \dot{q}_{29}) R_{6} + q_{24} S_{8}. $$

Because there are so many equations, I enlisted Mathematica to solve these equations for me.  However, it seems it is unable to decouple and solve the equations at the same time (at least with my basic plan).  Therefore, I assembled them into a matrix form such that

$$ \textbf{L} \ddot{\textbf{q}} + \textbf{R} \dot{\textbf{q}} + \textbf{S} {\textbf{q}} = \textbf{V}. $$

The matrices $ \textbf{L} $, $ \textbf{R} $, and $ \textbf{S} $ have dimensions 45 × 45 whose entries consist only of constants, many of which are simply zero.  In contrast, $ \textbf{V} $ is also a matrix of constants, but its dimensions are 45 × 1.  Finally, the matrix $ \textbf{q} $ is also 45 × 1, but consist of time-dependent variables $ q_{1} $, $ q_{2} $, et cetera.  Unfortunately, every matrix is singular (with the exception of $ \textbf{q} $), which merely complicates things.

I have researched this matter a little bit on this forum and elsewhere, and I cannot find anywhere that addresses this exact format.  To reference my equation for simplicity, all I can find is

- $ \textbf{V} $ equaling zero,
- $ \textbf{L} $, $ \textbf{R} $, or $ \textbf{S} $ equaling the
  identity matrix, or
- $ \textbf{L} $, $ \textbf{R} $, or $ \textbf{S} $ containing
  variables (such as the Cauchy-Euler equation).

Is it possible to program Mathematica to decouple these equations?  Is it even possible to do by hand?

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Edit: For what it's worth, here is the system in question:

```
eqlst = {
(*1*) vref==q1''[t]l1+(q1[t]-q2[t])/c1,
(*2*) (q1[t]-q2[t])/c1==q2'[t]r1+(q2'[t]-q3'[t])r2+(q2'[t]-q8'[t])r3,
(*3*) (q2'[t]-q3'[t])r2+(q13[t]+q12[t]-q3[t])/cμ1==(q3[t]-q4[t])/c4+(q3'[t]-q22'[t])rx1,
(*4*) (q3[t]-q4[t])/c4==(q4''[t]-q5''[t])l2,
(*5*) (q4''[t]-q5''[t])l2==(q5[t]-q6[t])/c5,
(*6*) (q5[t]-q6[t])/c5==(q6'[t]-q7'[t])r40+(q6[t]-q14[t])/c6,
(*7*) (q6'[t]-q7'[t])r40==q7''[t]l6+(q7[t]-q20[t]-q21[t])/cμ6+(q7'[t]-q14'[t]-q49'[t])rx6,
(*8*) (q2'[t]-q8'[t])r3==(q8[t]-q9[t])/c10,
(*9*) (q8[t]-q9[t])/c10==(q9[t]-q10[t])/c9,
(*10*) (q9[t]-q10[t])/c9==(q10[t]-q22[t])/c11,
(*11*) 0==(q11[t]-q22[t])/cπ1+(q11'[t]-iπ1-q13'[t])rπ1,
(*13*) (q11'[t]-iπ1-q13'[t])rπ1==(q13[t]+q12[t]-q3[t])/cμ1+    (q13'[t]-q14'[t])r01,
(*14*) (q6[t]-q14[t])/c6+(q7'[t]-q14'[t]-q49'[t])rx6+(q13'[t]-q14'[t])r01==(q14[t]+q49[t]-q19[t])/cπ6+(q14[t]-q31[t])/c7+(q14[t]-q28[t])/c33+(q14[t]-q24[t])/c12+q14'[t]r4,
(*15*) 0==q15'[t]rx5+(q15[t]-q17[t]-q18[t])/cμ5,
(*16*) 0==q16[t]/cπ5+(q16'[t]-iπ5-q18'[t])rπ5,
(*18*) (q16'[t]-iπ5-q18'[t])rπ5+(q15[t]-q17[t]-q18[t])/cμ5==    (q18'[t]-q49'[t])r05,
(*19*) (q14[t]+q49[t]-q19[t])/cπ6==(q19'[t]-iπ6-q21'[t])rπ6,
(*21*) (q19'[t]-iπ6-q21'[t])rπ6+(q7[t]-q20[t]-q21[t])/cμ6==(q21'[t]-q32'[t])r06,
(*22*) (q10[t]-q22[t])/c11+(q3'[t]-q22'[t])rx1+(q11[t]-q22[t])/cπ1==(q22[t]-q23[t])/c29,
(*23*) (q22[t]-q23[t])/c29==(q23''[t]-q24''[t])l3+(q23'[t]-q24'[t])r5,
(*24*) (q23''[t]-q24''[t])l3+(q23'[t]-q24'[t])r5+(q14[t]-q24[t])/c12==q24''[t]l4+(q24''[t]-q25''[t])l5+(q24'[t]-q29'[t])r6+q24[t]/c8,
(*25*) (q24''[t]-q25''[t])l5==(q25'[t]+q26'[t])rχ1+(q25''[t]+q26''[t])lχ1+(q25[t]+q26[t])/cχ1,
(*26*) 0==(q25'[t]+q26'[t])rχ1+(q25''[t]+q26''[t])lχ1+(q25[t]+q26[t])/cχ1+q26[t]/cχ0,
(*27*) 0==(q25'[t]+q26'[t])rχ1+(q25''[t]+q26''[t])lχ1+(q25[t]+q26[t])/cχ1+q14'[t]r4+q24''[t]l4,
(*28*) (q14[t]-q28[t])/c33==(q28'[t]-q29'[t])rS+q28'[t]r+(q28''[t]-q29''[t])lS,
(*29*) vtune+(q24'[t]-q29'[t])r6+(q28'[t]-q29'[t])rS+(q28''[t]-q29''[t])lS==q29[t]/cT+(q29'[t]-q31'[t])r18+q29'[t]r44,
(*30*) vtune==q29'[t]r44+q24[t]/c8,
(*31*) (q29'[t]-q31'[t])r18+(q14[t]-q31[t])/c7==(q31'[t]+q49'[t]-q32'[t])r42,
(*32*) (q31'[t]+q49'[t]-q32'[t])r42+(q21'[t]-q32'[t])r06==q32[t]/c16+(q32''[t]-q33''[t])l7+(q32'[t]-q33'[t])r10,
(*33*) (q32''[t]-q33''[t])l7+(q32'[t]-q33'[t])r10==q33''[t]l9+(q33[t]-q36[t])/cGS2,
(*34*) 0==(q34[t]-q35[t]-q36[t])/cDS2+q34'[t]rD2,
(*36*) (q33[t]-q36[t])/cGS2+(q34[t]-q35[t]-q36[t])/cDS2==(q36[t]-q37[t])/cGD2,
(*37*) (q36[t]-q37[t])/cGD2==(q37[t]-q39[t])/c18+(q37[t]-q40[t])/c19,
(*38*) 0==q38'[t]r9+(q38''[t]-q39''[t])l8,
(*39*) (q38''[t]-q39''[t])l8+(q37[t]-q39[t])/c18==(q39[t]-q44[t])/c15+q39'[t]rout+q39[t]/c34+(q39'[t]-q42'[t])r33+(q39''[t]-q40''[t])l11,
(*40*) (q39''[t]-q40''[t])l11+(q37[t]-q40[t])/c19==(q40''[t]-q41''[t])l13+(q40[t]-q41[t])/c32,
(*41*) (q40''[t]-q41''[t])l13+(q40[t]-q41[t])/c32==(q41'[t]-q42'[t])r31,
(*42*) (q41'[t]-q42'[t])r31+(q39'[t]-q42'[t])r33==q42'[t]r32,
(*43*) 0==q42'[t]r32+q39'[t]rout+q39[t]/c34,
(*44*) (q39[t]-q44[t])/c15==(q44[t]+q45[t])/c13,
(*45*) vref==q45''[t]l12+(q44[t]+q45[t])/c13,
(*46*) 0==q46[t]/c3+q46[t]/c26,
(*47*) 0==q47[t]/c3+q47[t]/c2,
(*48*) 0==q28'[t]r+q29[t]/cT,
(*49*) (q7'[t]-q14'[t]-q49'[t])rx6+(q18'[t]-q49'[t])r05==(q14[t]+q49[t]-q19[t])/cπ6+(q31'[t]+q49'[t]-q32'[t])r42+q49'[t]r41
 };
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141559/discussion-on-question-by-compnoob-decoupling-many-second-order-linear-odes).